# Installing two things at the same time on Linux

Tags: linux, installation, package-management

I noticed that package managers won't install things if they know that another package manager is open. So I was wondering if it's OK to install multiple things at the same time when using the terminal.

For example, if I type "make install" in one terminal, while that's going on, is it ok to type "sudo apt-get install package" in another terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only one program (GUI or not) can use the package manager at a time.  However, `make install` does not use the package manager.  It just runs the install target of the `Makefile`, which typically just copies files and sets permissions.

Comment: Running both at the same time might still introduce inconsistencies since `./configure` finds another system than `make`.

Comment: Also keep in mind your package manager will not be aware of anything you build separately so will not be able to use it as a dependency... Unless you build a package instead of make install-ing - checkinstall can make this easy in many cases: http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/

Comment: By the way, the reason (well, _a_ reason) that you can't/shouldn't run more than one instance of the package manager at a time is that it checks dependencies, and it needs to know that the information it gathers at the beginning about which dependencies are installed and which aren't remains valid while the packages are being installed. `make install` doesn't do any dependency checks so it doesn't have that issue.

Comment: Note that you can *specify* more than one package at a time: `sudo apt-get install package1 package2 package3`

Comment: @honk, that's a valid point.  You have to take care not to modify related parts of the system at the same time.  And `checkinstall` is useful if you want the package manager to be aware of what `make install` does.

Comment: Good to know. i was wondering about this also since im using linux now